# Python- How to use getText

Tags: python, multilingual, gettext

i am trying to make my application python application multilingual. I wrote the below code

transaltor.py

```
import gettext
gettext.bindtextdomain('ru', 'locales')
gettext.textdomain('ru')
_ = gettext.gettext
print(_('What kind of trip'))
```

and here is my project structure.

```
├── Pipfile.lock
├── __pycache__
│   └── constants.cpython-310.pyc
├── constants.py
├── locales
│   ├── ru
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       ├── django.po
│   │       └── ru.po
│   └── uz
│       └── LC_MESSAGES
│           ├── django.po
│           └── uz.po
└── translator.py
```

the output for the code is

```
What kind of trip
```

and expected output should be Russian translated

```
Выберите вариант полета
```

and I referred [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#gettext.bindtextdomain)

any help would be great. thank you in advance

Comment: Could you explain more about what you are going to do? build `main.py` to run `translator.py` that prints `'What kind of trip'`?

Comment: hey @JayPeerachai. the code that I mentioned on top is the code that I am running which is translator.py as mentioned. and the output for the code is below. but it should be `Выберите вариант полета` which is in Russian. but i am not getting that. instead i am getting the same english one.

Comment: this (https://simpleit.rocks/python/how-to-translate-a-python-project-with-gettext-the-easy-way/) may help.